# Making a mathematics quiz in python

Tags: python, math

```
import random

def mathquiz():
    name = str(input("Whats your name?:"))
    a = random.randint(1,10)
    b = random.randint(1,10)
    c = (a * b)
    timesby = ("*")
    print('what is', + a, timesby, + b)
    ans = input("Enter your answer here")
    if ans == c:
        print("Thats correct")
    else:
        print ("Incorrect the answer is", + c)
```

I am trying to create a maths quiz using random numbers and just say the question is 10 * 10 if i enter 100 if will say i have the wrong answer. Everything else works fine just this bit is wrong.

Comment: Maybe a type mismatch if `ans` is a string and `c` is an int.

Comment: The problem is that entered value by a user is a string and you compare string to int

Comment: [How can I read inputs as integers?](//stackoverflow.com/q/20449427)

Comment: `c = str(a * b)`

Comment: Probably also of interest for you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/8881141

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers)

Answer (score 2):

ans and c are of different types. Since you read ans from the console, it is a string, and not a number, while c is calculated through multiplying 2 numbers, so it is a number. there are 2 ways to fix this, convert ans to an int with int(ans) instead of ans, or convert c to a string with str(c) instead of c.